# Central Limit Theorem for gambling return ratio

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Consider a single bet with odds $o$ and thereby implied probability $1/o$.

Assume that the real probability $p$ is known.

Let $I$ be the stake, and $y$ the return from the bet. Then,

$\mathbb{E}(y) = I(po-1)$

Consider the case where you have $N$ such bets, and then define the win-ratio to be

$WR = \displaystyle\frac{\sum(return)}{\sum(bet)} = \displaystyle\frac{\sum_{i=1}^Ny_i}{\sum_{i=1}^NI_i}$.

My question is: would $WR$ be normally distributed by the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: If  the size of your bets are the same, or even different, but independently distributed, then yes.  But if you vary your bet based on previous results e.g. "double or nothing" then, no.

Comment: @DougM if they are scaled such that the return always will be $1000 if you win, would that be considered independently distrubuted?